# Data fetched from database is not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

The labels at the end of the code (highlighted in bold) are not displaying the data fetched from the sql server database and are empty when I run the code. I have tried if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) and var table = ds2.Tables[0];if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) both. Please reply to this query.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Response : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
      //in between code

        public void showdata()
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from signup1 where usid=''"+Session["user"]+"";
            cmd.Connection = con2;
            sda2.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda2.Fill(ds2);
            Label1.Text = "Thank you! Your sign up was successful. Below are the details you entered, please verify:";
                **Label2.Text = "First Name: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fname"].ToString();
                Label3.Text = "Last Name: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lname"].ToString();
                Label4.Text = "UserID: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["usid"].ToString();
                Label5.Text = "Password: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pswd"].ToString();
                Label6.Text = "Email: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["eid"].ToString();
                Label7.Text = "Security Question: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sq"].ToString();
                Label8.Text = "Security Answer: " + ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["sa"].ToString();**
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that are not great about this but perhaps your _first_ issue is that the syntax in your query is incorrect. See the part around `''`

Comment: Maybe there is no data in that column? Your code is pretty scary though. You need to read about and start using parameterized queries. You should not select all the columns either, only the ones you need. And storing password in plain text is borderline criminal. It should be salted and hashed.

Comment: @ZLK even after fixing that syntax error, the server error I am getting is Server Error in '/' Application There is no row at position 0.

Comment: @SeanLange I got your point, I want to display all the data being filled by the user. And this is not being used in any kind of professional environment. It's just out of curiosity that I coded this chunk. The session key takes in the userid that is uniques and I want to display the data for that particular id only.

Comment: OK. So is the data stored in the database? Your query syntax as posted in invalid so you should be getting an exception.

Comment: Yes the data is getting stored but is not being displayed while running. I corrected that syntax error as well. Which query syntax are you talking about?

Comment: @SeanLange Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.
This is the error.

Comment: Well, what does the user cookie look like and what does the column `usid` contain (e.g. datatype and what the data looks like)?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Put in some break points and figure out what you query is that you are executing. We can't debug this for you. We can't see your screen and don't have access to the database. You mention something about checking dt.Rows.Count but there is no dt in your code. You have to provide us some details here if you want some help.